# Group results by days in a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which one of the column is timestamp and I have the following query

> SELECT * FROM test WHERE (timepacket BETWEEN 2014-02-16 00:00:00 and 2014-02-19 00:00:00) AND (shift = 1)

But this query gives me all the rows between the date range given in sql query. Thus my question is how can group the results from above query according to dates. Like

> 2014-02-16
>
> 1st row
>
> 2nd row
>
> 3rd row
>
> 2014-02-17
>
> 1st row
>
> 2nd row
>
> 3rd row
>
> 4th row

and so on

Comment: try this SELECT * FROM test WHERE (timepacket BETWEEN 2014-02-16 00:00:00 and 2014-02-19 00:00:00) AND (shift = 1) group by DATE(timepacket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE 
timepacket BETWEEN '2014-02-16 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-19 00:00:00' 
AND shift = 1 
GROUP BY timepacket;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY  or *Order by*

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (timepacket BETWEEN 2014-02-16 00:00:00 and 2014-02-19 00:00:00)
 AND (shift = 1) GROUP BY timepacket
```

Answer (score 0):

Even your query is not much clear but as per my understanding you want to do ordering based on date, if it is then use below query-

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (timepacket BETWEEN 2014-02-16 00:00:00 and 2014-02-19 00:00:00) AND shift = 1 order by date(timepacket);
```